# Nested LINQ Nightmare, calculating %completed

Tags: c#, linq, mvc

This code horrifies and scares me. *I wrote this.*

```
public IQueryable<StudentTrack> StudentTracks(int employeeId)
{

    IQueryable<StudentTrack> EducationPortalStudentTracks =
        from studentTrack in _dbContext.EducationPortalStudentTracks
        join track in _dbContext.EducationPortalTracks on studentTrack.TrackId equals track.Id
        orderby track.Id
        where studentTrack.EmployeeId == employeeId
        select new StudentTrack
        {
            Id = studentTrack.Id,
            TrackId = studentTrack.TrackId,
            Name = track.Name,
            Deadline = studentTrack.Deadline,

            // this is where it gets bad
            PercentComplete = (from doesntMatter in _dbContext.EducationPortalStudentCourses
                               let courses = (from studentCourse in _dbContext.EducationPortalStudentCourses
                                              join studentTrack_ in _dbContext.EducationPortalStudentTracks on studentCourse.TrackId equals studentTrack_.TrackId
                                              where studentTrack.Id == studentTrack.Id && studentTrack.EmployeeId == studentCourse.EmployeeId
                                              select studentCourse)
                               select courses.Where(x => x.Status == true).Count() * 100 / courses.Count()).FirstOrDefault()

        };
    return EducationPortalStudentTracks;
}
```

Let me explain how this fits in to the rest of the application. On the top level, a Kendo Grid control calls an MVC controller for its data. That controller calls another controller, which calls this. So this method returns the data which populates a grid in the UI. That grid lists all of the `StudentTracks` in the database. In order to return the `StudentTracks`, this method does a little bit of Linq and returns a series of `StudentTrack` objects.

So the problem starts with the `PercentComplete` field. To calculate the value for that field, we first find all of the children `StudentCourses`. We then figure out how many of the `StudentCourses` are complete (a.k.a. have True in the `Status` column) and divide that by the total number of `StudentCourses`.

Anyway, this is what I came up with. I'm not pleased with it, but I don't know how to do it any better. Any ideas on how I can make this a little more elegant?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Break it down into more methods. `StudentTracks` has multiple responsibilities, you could *extract a private method* whose job would be to `CalculatePercentCompletion(studentTrack)`, making your method look like this:

```
public IQueryable<StudentTrack> StudentTracks(int employeeId)
{
    IQueryable<StudentTrack> EducationPortalStudentTracks =
        from studentTrack in _dbContext.EducationPortalStudentTracks
        join track in _dbContext.EducationPortalTracks on studentTrack.TrackId equals track.Id
        orderby track.Id
        where studentTrack.EmployeeId == employeeId
        select new StudentTrack
        {
            Id = studentTrack.Id,
            TrackId = studentTrack.TrackId,
            Name = track.Name,
            Deadline = studentTrack.Deadline,
            PercentComplete = CalculatePercentCompletion(studentTrack)    
        };

    return EducationPortalStudentTracks;
}
```

Then `CalculatePercentCompletion` could look like this:

```
private int CalculatePercentCompletion(StudentTrack studentTrack)
{
    return (from doesntMatter in _dbContext.EducationPortalStudentCourses
            let courses = (from studentCourse in _dbContext.EducationPortalStudentCourses
                           join studentTrack_ in _dbContext.EducationPortalStudentTracks on studentCourse.TrackId equals studentTrack_.TrackId
                           where studentTrack.Id == studentTrack.Id && studentTrack.EmployeeId == studentCourse.EmployeeId
                           select studentCourse)
            select courses.Where(x => x.Status == true).Count() * 100 / courses.Count()).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

...Which is still horrible.

Why are you using the query syntax? If you have *navigation properties* on your entities (assuming EF), I find this would be much easier to parse:

```
public IQueryable<StudentTrack> StudentTracks(int employeeId)
{
    return _dbContext.EducationPortalStudentTracks
                     .Where(studentTrack => studentTrack.EmployeeId == employeeId)
                     .OrderBy(studentTrack => studentTrack.Track.Id)
                     .Select(studentTrack => 
                         new StudentTrack
                         {
                             Id = studentTrack.Id,
                             TrackId = studentTrack.TrackId,
                             Name = studentTrack.Track.Name,  
                             Deadline = studentTrack.Deadline,
                             PercentComplete = CalculatePercentCompletion(studentTrack)
                         });
}
```

In `CalculatePercentCompletion` the `doesntMatter` part makes it pretty confusing, I'm not sure but I *think* this could be equivalent:

```
private int CalculatePercentCompletion(StudentTrack studentTrack)
{
    var courses = _dbContext.EducationPortalStudentCourses
                            .Where(course => course.TrackId == studentTrack.Id
                                          && course.EmployeeId == studentTrack.EmployeeId)
                            .ToList();
    return courses.Count(course => course.Status == true) * 100 / courses.Count
}
```

Why the `.ToList()` call? You want to *materialize* your query only when you need to - this method needs to know *what the courses are for a given `studentTrack`*, in order to count the number of courses with `Status == true`, multiply that by 100 and divide by the total number of courses.

Your code iterates `courses` twice, in the two `Count()` calls.

And the intent is not exactly clear because of the `doesntMatter` in the `from` clause, and the `.FirstOrDefault()` call makes it look like we're looking at an `IEnumerable<int>` when we're really all materialized at that point and we either have zero or one values selected (if I get this correctly).

The `status == true` part is confusing. Normally I would have written it as `.Where(course => course.Status)` to avoid comparing a Boolean with a Boolean value, but `Status` is really a poor name and doing that would have made it harder to understand what's going on. I suggest you rename `Status` to whatever `IsCompleted`, so the where condition can read as `.Where(course => course.IsCompleted)`, which is crystal-clear.

---

I think exposing `IQueryable<T>` to your UI is a bad idea. `StudentTracks` should return an `IEnumerable<StudentTrack>` instead, your grid should be able to work off that just as well.

I would leave the last `Select` to Linq-to-Objects, and materialize the query just after the `OrderBy` call:

```
public IEnumerable<StudentTrack> GetStudentTracks(int employeeId)
{
    return _dbContext.EducationPortalStudentTracks
                     .Where(studentTrack => studentTrack.EmployeeId == employeeId)
                     .OrderBy(studentTrack => studentTrack.Track.Id)
                     .ToList()
                     .Select(studentTrack => 
                         new StudentTrack
                         {
                             Id = studentTrack.Id,
                             TrackId = studentTrack.TrackId,
                             Name = studentTrack.Track.Name,  
                             Deadline = studentTrack.Deadline,
                             PercentComplete = CalculatePercentCompletion(studentTrack)
                         });
}
```

The problem with exposing `IQueryable<T>` to your client code, is that you allow that code to modify the SQL being generated, and potentially to break your query with calls that Linq-to-Entities cannot translate to SQL. The grid in your UI doesn't *need* an `IQueryable<T>`.

Comment: Does method syntax avoid [this error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13887296/linq-to-entities-does-not-recognize-the-method-int32-int32system-string-meth)?

Comment: No, but proper/ timely materialization does (`.ToList()` ;)

Comment: You left out a join on your method syntax example ;) (I know how to do joins, I thought you'd want to know for completeness's sake.)